# How to make sure responseText does not return Oracle errors when something cannot be inserted into databse

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I've got my website, a bunch of stuff is sent through JavaScript to PHP, if it all goes well, PHP returns a response that says something like "user created succesfully" but if it doesn't then it should only return, "user could not be created" or "username already exists", however it doesn't and instead it throws back a bunch of Oracle Errors. Is there anyway to make sure PHP doesn't send that, and just sends one of those two strings?

This is my JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = function findSubmitButton() {
    var button = document.querySelector(".send_info").addEventListener("click", serverInteraction); /*Unobtrusive javascript listener, added to 
                                                                                                    create account button in html*/
}


function serverInteraction() {
  var xmlhttp;
  var inputArray;
  var finalArray = [];
  var JSONArray;
  var userId;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        /* Used for IE7+,FireFox, Opera, Chrome, Safari */
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   /* Compatibility for IE6 browsers */
  } else {
      throw new Error("Your browser is not compatible with XMLHTTP");
      return false;
  }

  /* The following section validates if the required inputs have text in them and if the password fields match*/
  inputArray = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")
  if (inputArray[1].value != inputArray[2].value){
      alert("Password doesn't match, please make sure your password matches")
      return false;
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
      if (inputArray[i].value == ""){
          alert("Please fill out all of the fields");
          return false;
      }
        finalArray[i] = inputArray[i].value;
  }
    console.log(finalArray);
    JSONArray = JSON.stringify({finalArray: finalArray}); 
    console.log(JSONArray);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            if (confirm(xmlhttp.responseText)){
                window.location = 'index.html'
            }  
          }
      }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","php/sendUserInfo.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSONArray);
}
```

Here's PHP, which is the one causing the problems:

```
<?php

    $db_connection = oci_connect('User', 'password', 'localhost/database');  /*Used to establish connection between database and server*/                                                                                                         
    $finalArray = file_get_contents('php://input');                                   /*Data retrieval*/            
    $finalArray = json_decode($finalArray,true);                                      /*JSON decoding*/
    $error;                 

    $username = $finalArray['finalArray'][0];              /* These variables are the data to be sent to the database */
    $password = $finalArray['finalArray'][1];
    $email = $finalArray['finalArray'][3];
    $name = $finalArray['finalArray'][4];
    $firstLastName = $finalArray['finalArray'][5];
    $secondLastName = $finalArray['finalArray'][6];

    $sqlVariableUsuarioTable = 'CALL usuario_package.add_usuario(:username, :password)';  /* SQL statement to send */
    $sqlVariablePersonTable = 'CALL person_package.add_person(:name, :first_ln, :second_ln, :username_person)';
    $sqlVariableEmailTable = 'CALL email_package.add_email(:email)';
    $dataToInsertUsuario = oci_parse($db_connection, $sqlVariableUsuarioTable);                         /* prepares statements to be sent to database */
    $dataToInsertPerson = oci_parse($db_connection, $sqlVariablePersonTable);
    $dataToInsertEmail= oci_parse($db_connection, $sqlVariableEmailTable);


    if(!$db_connection){                                    /* checks if connection with the database works */
        exit ("Server could not connect to database");
    }

    oci_bind_by_name($dataToInsertUsuario, ':username', $username);                    /* binds variables to their string names */
    oci_bind_by_name($dataToInsertUsuario, ':password', $password);
    oci_bind_by_name($dataToInsertEmail, ':email', $email);
    oci_bind_by_name($dataToInsertPerson, ':name', $name);
    oci_bind_by_name($dataToInsertPerson, ':first_ln', $firstLastName);
    oci_bind_by_name($dataToInsertPerson, ':second_ln', $secondLastName);
    oci_bind_by_name($dataToInsertPerson, ':username_person', $username);


    $arrayOfDataToSend[0] = $dataToInsertUsuario;
    $arrayOfDataToSend[1] = $dataToInsertEmail;
    $arrayOfDataToSend[2] = $dataToInsertPerson;

    foreach ($arrayOfDataToSend as $value){
        oci_execute($value);
        if(oci_error($value)['code'] == 00001){
            oci_rollback($db_connection);
            exit ("The username or email you have entered already exists");
        } else if (oci_error() != false){
            oci_rollback($db_connection);
            exit ("An error has occured with the database");
        }

    }
    exit ("Account succesfully created");
    oci_close($db_connection);

?>
```

I know its possible to filter, or to check that the user doesn't exist before inserting data, either way I'm sure there's a simpler solution. I'd appreciate if anyone could help me out with that. I'm really new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a try/catch block around the code in your php

```
foreach ($arrayOfDataToSend as $value){
    try {
        oci_execute($value);
        exit ("Account successfully created");
    } catch {
        exit ("An error has occured with the database");    
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: I see, thank you, I can't believe I did not think of doing that to be honest.

Comment: Keep in mind its poor practice to use try/catch for logic flow. IE to check if the user exists you shouldn't rely on an error message from oracle, you will want to check first and only run the insert statement if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: I see, maybe I should do that, I just didn't want to have to rely on that, but yeah I guess it is the best solution.